# iOS 7 navigation bar background blur effect is not working in iPhone4

Tags: ios, ios7

In iPhone4 the default iOS7 translucent/blurred effect of the navigation bar is not working. I used the following code for iOS7 theme effect.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Note: In iPhone4, iOS 7.1.2 AppStore also doesn't have that effect. Whereas in iPhone 5 and other devices has the default iOS 7 theme effect on it's applications like AppStore, Itunes...etc.

Is there any way to achieve this particular UI effect in iPhone 4 , iOS 7. And your thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone 4 has this feature removed for performance reasons—if you absolutely require this functionality, look on Github for [custom implementations](https://github.com/search?q=ios%207%20blur&ref=opensearch) that will work on other devices.

Just remember that Apple removed this feature for a reason, and it may be best to simply leave it be!

Comment: Yes It's not available in iPhone4 that I came to know from the apps like AppStore, Itunes...etc. But my question is, Is there a way to bring this ui effect, by any customized technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .Let me know if it doesn't work i will give another solution

```
 self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```